# Android SimpleDateFormat does not support "X" pattern letter, even though documentation states otherwise

Tags: android, simpledateformat

When I use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.getDefault())` Android throws runtime exception "Unknown pattern character 'X'". According to https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html "X" is perfectly valid. Also, I know that Java 6 doesn't support 'X' (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but Java 7 does (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). My Android code is compiled to Java 7... This is weirding me out. Why is this happening?

Comment: did you try to use Z instead of X for the Timezone? something like yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ

Comment: "Z" token works indeed. But I want to understand why documentation says one thing but in my case it doesn't work. Second, I was sure that because SDT on Android works in similar way to Java 7's SDT, I could write unit tests for the DateUtil that was doing different conversions. Because unit tests are not launched on Android platform, I got into a situation where all unit tests were green, but on the device the tested code was throwing runtime exception.

Comment: Also, if I use 'Z', then it's vice-versa - on device everything works, but unit tests are not working correctly, because with 'Z' on Java something like "+02:00" is lost. And if I use 'ZZZZZ', then it doesn't work on Java JVM at all. Something like that.

Comment: I just read a Bug report of the Swagger API that X is not supported at Android https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1573

Comment: I also read the same thread on my quest to understand the problem. Samuelg there states that "The Android version of SimpleDateFormat does not support XXX." and points to the same Android docs I pointed in my question. Those docs clearly state that X is supported (now, on Feb 16, 2017). We have to consider that he wrote that on Nov 16, 2015...

Comment: I suspect, X was introduced later, not in API-level 1. Maybe you have first to update your Android version to make it working. The documentation is not clear at all about this version problem.

Comment: In those docs you can easily switch API level (left top corner). Also, in my project we support API level 16 and above and it still wasn't working with X.

Comment: my date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX , and i want my output as 2017-08-24T11:53:14054. How can i get this in android? Did anyone find solution to this?